# Data entry form in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was wondering if anyone knows what a simplest way to create a data entry form in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation would be.  Basicly I am looking to create a form that will submit its data to a custom list on the site, I don't want the users to interact with the list directly but use the form to enter data  instead.

Also I can't use Designer or InfoPath, not being able to use these is what is causing the problem it seems.  Just curious if anyone else has done something like this or could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Just why can't you use Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Its for a client and they said they would rather not,  I am just wondering if it is possible to even do this without Designer or feasible to do so

Comment: Possible yes. Feasible, only if your job is no more complicated than having a "Hello World" page. Sharepoint Designer is even free, I don't see why one should impose such a limitation.

Comment: Also you'll get faster, better feedback on Sharepoint related questions at [the corresponding site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) in the Stack Exchange.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that site, thank you for your help Renan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every list is born with forms by default - one for item creation, one for edition and one for displaying. If you use content types, then you get a trio of these for each different type.

You never interact with the list directly, you do it through these forms. If you can't use either Infopath nor Sharepoint Designer, you can still edit them by clicking on the **Page** tab, then the **Edit Page** button. From there you can add or remove web parts, and connect them among themselves.

However, the amount of control you have is too limited when compared to editing pages through either of the tools or mentioned, or Visual Studio. For example, there is no straightforward way to add or remove list fields based on content type. Be prepared for ever increasing frustration if you can't use those tools.